# Rewrite a non-existent directory name to a file

Tags: .htaccess

How would I rewrite a non-existent directory name to a file.

domain.php/press

to

domain.php/news/index.php

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite `domain.com/press` to `domain.com/news/index.php` you can use the following Rewrite command in your `.htaccess` or `server.config` file.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/?press/?$ /news/index.php [L]
```