# How can you fetch a name from a Directory like you do with $_GET in PHP?

Tags: php

Here is how you get a variable name for a get statement

By link:
    http://www.example.com/index.php?foldername

By form:

```
<form method="get" action = "">
    <input type="text" name ="adsda" />
</form>


<?php
foreach ($_GET as $name => $val)
{
     echo htmlspecialchars($name . ': ' . $val) . "\n";
}
?>
```

How can you get a name from a directory name in PHP?

```
http://www.example.com/foldername1
http://www.example.com/foldername2
```

Can you do it without creating folders?  (For example if someone did this for searching something)

Comment: another good way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310091/rewrite-a-non-existent-directory-name-to-a-file

Comment: Your comments helped me find this https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/